# Tensorflow Python 3.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv, python-venv

Tensorflow version for Python 3.7

Any news about tensorflow update for python 3.7. When I try to install tensorflow inside my venv like:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

I got an error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) 
>   No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: I had the same question this morning. As far as I know, still no Python 3.7 compatibility.

Comment: Not available yet, it seems like it is schedule for tensorflow 1.13 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23478

Answer (score 10):

Python 3.7 is now supported officially in TensorFlow 1.13.1:

> Major Features and Improvements
>
> - TensorFlow Lite has moved from contrib to core. This means that
>     Python modules are under tf.lite and source code is now under
>     tensorflow/lite rather than tensorflow/contrib/lite.
> - TensorFlow GPU binaries are now built against CUDA 10 and TensorRT 5.0.
> - Support for Python3.7 on all operating systems.
> - Moved NCCL to core.

[source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.13.1)

Comment: FYI, I have tried with 3.7.1 but it's not working. let us know if you tried the same and success

Comment: It works on Windows 10 with Anaconda and python 3.7.3

Answer (score 3):

You can see the status of the move to 3.7 here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20517

Comment: Ty, but howcome Spyder works with tensorflow, and Sypder is built on Python 3.7?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should download and set up the anaconda via [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section) and then open anaconda prompt and then follow these steps via [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip). Fourthly, you should use '`pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow==1.14.0`' to install TensorFlow 1.14 on Conda Finally, you can use TensorFlow that is version 1.14 on python 3.7

Have a Great Time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a 64-bit version of Python and 3.7 does not work with tensorflow right now, I suggest a downgrade to 3.6.x

Answer (score 0):

I tried many versions of the tensorflow with python 3.7 and failed. But finally tensorflow version 1.14 worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as you- I was using Python 3.7 32-bit on Windows 10 64-bit machine. 
Since **TensorFlow doesn't support 32-bit Python** hence it said that "No matching distribution found for TensorFlow".

What worked for me is that I uninstalled the 32-bit Python version and installed the 64-bit Python version and `pip install tensorflow` worked immediately for downloading TensorFlow 2.2.0. Note that TensorFlow now supports till Python 3.8.

**Check if you have the 32-bit version of Python.** To check whether you have the 32-bit version or 64-bit version, type IDLE in the search bar and you will be able to tell which version it is.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, for Windows users, 
`pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`
works with python_3.7(64-bit) and at least pip 19.0

Comment: ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform